# Understanding concept of proof by induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction, proof-explanation

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the concept of proving by induction in certain cases, and I was hoping you could answer my question, which is broken down into 2 parts. I will use the following example to help illustrate my confusion.

[image]

Naturally, the base case is shown to be true. We would then assume that the following holds:

$$f(k) = 8^k - 3^k$$ is divisible by 5. Then we show that:

$$f(k+1) = 8\cdot8^k - 3\cdot3^k$$

Here's my first issue. I managed to solve this by showing that this can be re-written as:

$$f(k+1)=8(8^k-(3/8)3^k)=8\cdot8^k-8\cdot3^k+5\cdot3k^k$$
$$=8f(k)+5\cdot3^k$$

In the solutions, it says that since f(k) is divisible by 5, and the other term is also divisible by 5, then f(k+1) is also divisible by 5. Alternatively, it also shown that:

$$f(k+1) -8f(k) = 5\cdot3^k$$

Here are my questions:

1. Surely the entire proof rests on the assumption that f(k) is divisible by 5? If, say, it fails at f(3), then we haven't proved anything and the entire proof fails. It just seems a little circular to me, at least in this case.
2. Shouldn't we be rather aiming to prove the following algebraically?

$$ f(k+1) = 5\cdot (\mathrm{some\:function})$$
or
$$f(k+1) - f(k) = 5\cdot (\mathrm{some\:function})$$

instead of having 8f(k)? Even if using the solution works, I would imagine that working out one of these two alternatives should also be possible? I've seen other examples where this is exactly the case i.e. you show that f(k+1) - f(k) has a factor of the divisor in the answer, so therefore f(k+1) = f(k) + divisor*answer is what you need. I'll show another example to prove my point.

[image]

Long story short, you get the following:

$$f(k+1) - f(k) = 4(2(3^2k))$$

So why isn't it doable for the first question I showed?

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118138/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-podobinski-understanding-concept-of-proof-by-in).

Answer (score 2):

Consider a bunch of dominoes which, for all you know, are standing up in a line. These facts are brought to your attention:

1. The first domino has actually fallen over.
2. When one domino falls over, the next in line one also falls over.

You are free to conclude that all of the dominos have fallen over. Lets follow this setup for your example.

1. Since $8^1-3^1 = 5^1$, $f(1)$ is divisible by 5. (thus the first domino has fallen)

We need to show that one domino falling causes the next one to fall. That is, we need to show: if some $f(k)$ is divisible by $5$, then the next one $f(k+1)$ will also be divisible by 5.

2. You showed that $f(k+1)=8f(k)+5\cdot3^k$ (nice work). So, if $f(k)$ is divisible by 5, and since certainly $5\cdot3^k$ is divisible by 5, we get that the $f(k+1)$ must be divisible by 5. (one domino falling causes the next to fall)

You conclude that all of the dominoes fall.

Comment: My issue is with the following "So, since f(k) is divisible by 5..."; in that simply assuming it works for some k. Let me give a counter example. Say instead, the function was something like 7^k - 2. It is divisible by 5 for the base case (k=1). Then I assume that it works for all k. Then I prove that it works for k+1. I suppose, similar to proof by contradiction, if I cannot do this, then it shows that my assumption for k is false? Is that essentially it?

Comment: @DanielPodobinski: You *don't* assume that it holds for all $k$. You just show that if it *were* to hold for some $k$, then it would also hold for $k+1$. Then you use that for $k=1$ it does, in fact, hold. So it also holds for 1+1=2. So for $k=2$ it does, in fact, hold, so it also holds for 2+1=3. Repeat as far as you like.

Comment: @DanielPodobinski: No, how would it?

Answer (score 1):

The base case is important for the same reason.

You showed that it is true for $k=1$
You also showed that if it is true for $f(k)$ then it is also true for $f(k+1)$

Therefore,
It is true for $f(1)$ then it is true for $f(2)$
It is true for $f(2)$ then it is true for $f(3)$ and so on...

Hence it is true for all natural numbers

Answer (score 0):

This is about your point #2.

For $f(k) = 8^k - 3^k$, we have
$$
f(k+1) - f(k) = 7 \cdot 8^k - 2 \cdot 3^k = 5 \cdot 8^k + 2(8^k-3^k) = 5 \cdot 8^k + 2f(k)
$$
and both terms are multiples of $5$.

As you say, ideally, $f(k+1) - f(k)$ would be a clear multiple of $5$. But it is not necessary to consider $f(k+1) - f(k)$. For instance, $f(k+1) - af(k)$ will do, for any $a$. In the case at hand, $a=3$ works, as the computation above shows:
$$
f(k+1) - 3f(k) = 5 \cdot 8^k
$$
You're not expected to guess $a=3$. Simplifying $f(k+1) - f(k)$ is a great starting point.

Comment: In your first line, I can see that obviously "5*8^k" is a multiple of 5, but the second "2(8^k - 3^k)"? Am I not seeing something obvious?

Comment: @Daniel, $2(8^k - 3^k)=2f(k)$

Comment: Yes I see that now, but perhaps my issue is that $f(k+1)-af(k)$ must also be a multiple of 5; to me it was not so intuitive that if $f(k+1) - f(k)$ is a multiple of 5, say, then the above must also be true. I believe the root of my problem was believing that it was not the case.